# What happened to the auto-inserted text for the "other" off-topic close reason?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, off-topic, close-dialog

The `"This question appears to be off topic because it's about"` text that used to show up in the "other" off-topic close reason now just shows up in the background and disappears when you start typing.

Why was this changed?

I would like it changed back, but I supposed there was a reason behind the change, so I'd just ask why.

But rather than just changing it back, I think it should be changed to something like:

> This question doesn't appear to conform to Stack Overflow guidelines as it's about

Because many new users don't know what "off topic" means.

It used to look like this:

[image]

But now it looks like this: (the text disappears when you start typing)

[image]

Comment: I agree, having it there saved me a lot of typing, and standardised beginning for such messages made them look more uniform and neater. And if someone didn't like them, h could write from scratch none the less.

Comment: I assume this is a bug...

Comment: @JanDvorak Seems like strange behaviour for a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This change was rolled back with the latest build (which is rolling out as I write this).

We may still make some changes around there to make it clearer that a comment is being created (or tweak the text like you suggested), but this "new" version was a regression in terms of usability.

Comment: As I suggested in the removed answer, it might also be nice to somehow highlight such a comment differently to understand its implications compared to a usual vote

Comment: @tobias maybe the close vote comment should always start with an (unremovable) "voting to close;"

Comment: @jan basically something like that, but ideally it would be unfakeable